# select classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="myChild">one</p>
<p class="myChild">two</p>
<p class="myChild">three</p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//code that selects the second and the third myChild class name

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here i have 3 p tags with myChild class, i want to select the second and the last one using jQuery to do that, and know how to manipulate with that

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/eq -- or just assign unique IDs to those elements.

Comment: @Blazemonger index is hardly going to help him achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `slice()` to select a subset of results:

```
$(".myChild").slice(1);
```

This will remove the first `myChild` element and return the rest.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnzn3/)

---

If you want to specify a start and end point to slice at then you supply two parameters:

```
$(".myChild").slice(1,3);
```

[**Another fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnzn3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

just use the not filter and pass it eq(0) which is basically stripping out the first result

```
$('.myChild').not(':eq(0)');
```

or for the shortest way and using only the selector engine

```
$('.myChild:not(:eq(0))')
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/D5Ngh/

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for the remaining except first one, you can use `:not(0)`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/gg4Qa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(".myChild")` will return a `HTMLCollection` (sort of like an array) of objects - you can iterate though this or directly reference positions in that collection. e.g. `$(".myChild").eq(1)` for the 2nd items and `$(".myChild").eq(2)` for the 3rd item.